# Can anyone share a .bak file of TFS complete collection, TFS 2012 sample with a lot of data

Tags: tfs, sample-data

Can anyone share a .bak file of TFS complete collection to test and see the options of burn down and iteration velocity, but don't have enough data on one day. I have downloaded the FabrkPrice.bak but it was for TFS 2013 and I have to update TFS, I want one for TFS 2012 please

Comment: No,but  I just review it and read. Looks amazing, I'll try it and give my feedback after install. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, that helped me, but is there any complete sample for TFS online? please

Comment: @jessehouwing Since your solution helps Vanessa, you can post it in a answer in order to let Vanessa mark it as answer. Vanessa, I don't think there is the sample for TFS online, except anyone add your account to his VSTS. You can try to migrate data to VSTS through OpsHub tool (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2).

Comment: Great! thanks really. and yes please go ahead and post as answer. It was really helpful.

Comment: You can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

For TFS, there have always been the Brian Keller VM's. There are downloads for every major version of TFS:

- 2015: http://vsalmvm.azurewebsites.net/
- 2013 & 2012: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/briankel/2013/04/17/list-of-all-visual-studio-alm-virtual-machines/

For VSTS there are a few alternatives. One is to import the Brian Keller VM into VSTS. You'd have to upgrade it to 2015 update 3 and would probably need to tweak the work item schema a bit. The problem with this solution is that while the Brian Keller VM's always start at the same point in time, your VSTS account will start to lag. So while the diagrams and graphs all look nice now, they're going to be behind after a week.

- OpsHub TFS Migration tool
- Microsoft High Fidelity Import (currently in closed beta)

Another option is the Sample Data Widget. It can be used to pre-populate a VSTS account with data so that it looks good for demo purposes. It doesn't populate all the kinds of data you'd get from the Brian Keller VM, but you'd get a nice backlog and burndown:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/03/25/sample-data-widget/
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.SampleDataWidget